# How to add nested view in Jenkins using groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-cli

I am trying to add a nested view using groovy script but is failing

```
Jenkins.instance.instance.addView(new hudson.plugins.nested__view.NestedView("Sample View"))
```

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class hudson.plugins.nested__view.NestedView 
 @ line 3, column 35.
   Jenkins.instance.instance.addView(new hudson.plugins.nested__view.NestedView("ViewX"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me in the Jenkins script console:

```
Jenkins.instance.addView(new hudson.plugins.nested_view.NestedView("Sample View"))
```